# how can I find specific item in array?

Tags: javascript

I need to find some items in array and filterd it for show in DOM, for example I want to find any title that I click on it.but it doesn't work.my code is:

```js
let addBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.cart-btn')
let i
const shoppingCart = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('myProduct', JSON.stringify(products))
    const getStorage = localStorage.getItem('myProduct')
    const finalProducts = JSON.parse(getStorage)
    finalProducts.map(item => {
        if (item.id === products.id) {
            console.log(item.title)
        } else {
            console.log("Not found")
        }
    })
    console.log(finalProducts.title)
}
for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    addBtn[i].addEventListener('click', shoppingCart)
}
```

Comment: you can try with  filter function on Array.

Comment: Please add a minimal working of this code. including relevant HTML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.flter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function like so:

```
finalProducts.filter(item => item.id === products.id)
```

In your code replace `map()` function with `filter()` function.

```js
let addBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.cart-btn')

const shoppingCart = (itemid) => {

    localStorage.setItem('myProduct', JSON.stringify(products))
    const getStorage = localStorage.getItem('myProduct')
    const finalProducts = JSON.parse(getStorage)

    let selected = finalProducts.filter(item => item.id === itemid)
    if (selected.length>0)
        console.log(selected[i].title)
    else
        console.log('Not found: ' + itemid)
}

for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    addBtn[i].addEventListener('click', _ => { shoppingCart(i) })
}
```

Comment: it just say:
 Not found: undefined

Comment: Looks like your `products` is an array. So `products.id` you are using is likely `undefined`. Do you know what id you should be searching for?

Comment: my product is:
const products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'T-Shirt',
        price: 98,
        quantity: 10
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Shoes',
        price: 70,
        quantity: 17
    }
]

Comment: There is `id=1` and `id=2`, which one do you want to search?

Comment: You will either need `finalProducts.filter(item => item.id === products[0].id)` or `finalProducts.filter(item => item.id === products[1].id)`

Comment: could you check my cod in 'codepen.io' Please? https://codepen.io/parisahs/pen/xxVqapO
actually I want each button I click, that return me name of that product

Comment: Thank you dear Rahul
it work correctly with a loop
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach and filter. You can try something like this.

```js
finalProducts.forEach(item => {
    let itemFound = products.filter(product => product.id === item.id)
    console.log(itemFound.title)
})
```

Comment: Dear Rama, actually it doesn't work
thanks for your answer